# rails add to json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I've done this before, but can't remember how its done now.

Have one json response from foursquare which includes:

```
"hereNow"=>{"count"=>1, "groups"=>[{"type"=>"friends", "name"=>"friends here", "count"=>0, "items"=>[]}, ...]}
```

I respond with @place (which is the location info) but want to pass the names and images to my view as json.

thought is was something like `@place['hereNow'] << response['venue']['hereNow']` to include it to my `render :json => @place`

Comment: What is @place['hereNow'] before you assign to it? What do you want it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the point is: the received `json` is a `string` so you can't work on it directly.

So two steps here:

- convert the received `json` to a `Hash`
- easily add whatever you desire to the `Hash`
- convert the `hash` back to `json`

There are great examples [here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/).

In a nutshell:

```
j = ActiveSupport::JSON
hash = { :color => ["red", "green", "jellow"], :date => Time.now }
json_string    = j.encode hash
recreated_hash = j.decode json_string
```

Comment: for me it was as simple as `hash = { :hereNow => response['venue']['hereNow'] }`.  Thanks.